# Debug C++ code (add two very big numbers)

Tags: c++, arrays, string

This code is supposed to get two very big numbers and add them together. Just iostream and string library allowed.

Example input:

```
132163162986831298132869132968213689316298613298681329689312682136312621382931628613286831286921968312698312698132682136893162986832168312698132
8312961362983126893162986312986832196893126813268932169831268912869621386893126893126891326831268361298621398631286831269813268312698132689312683612986892136813268312698312698321686312986312986893216831268921368321698132689312698132689321683126893216986893216893126813268931286931629886312
```

Example output:

```
8312961362983126893162986312986832196893126813268932169831268912869621386893126893126891326831268361298621398631286831269813268312698132689312683745150055123644566445567445666535375629284926285574546520581603504634319515620941311419520608605095205915299591349575263706431918119099942584444
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    string num1 , num2 ,sum;
    getline(cin,num1);
    getline(cin,num2);
    if (num2.length() > num1.length())
    {
        num2.swap(num1);
    }
    std::reverse(num1.begin(), num1.end());
    std::reverse(num2.begin(), num2.end());
    while(num2.length() < num1.length())
        num2.push_back('0');
    size_t lnth = num1.length();
    unsigned tmp , holder=0;
    for (size_t i = 0;i < lnth ; i++){
        tmp = (num1[i] - '0') + (num2[i] - '0') + holder;
        sum.push_back(tmp % 10 + '0');
        holder = tmp / 10;
    }
    if(holder > 0){
        sum.push_back('0' + holder);
    }
    while(!sum.empty()){
        if (sum[sum.length() - 1] == '0'){
            sum.pop_back();
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    std::reverse(sum.begin(), sum.end());
    cout << sum;
}
```

I' getting some correct and some wrong answers;

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, given `size_t i`, the condition `i >= 0` is always true by definition.

This is because `size_t` yields a 2s-complement unsigned representation.

Therefore, the loop `for (size_t i = whatever; i >= 0; i--)` will just run forever, or until "something bad happens".

Answer (score 0):

Did you know `std::string` has a wonderful feature called "reverse iterators"?
It makes your life a whole lot easier:

```
auto it1 = str1.crbegin(), it2 = str2.crbegin();
int carry = 0;
std::string result;
while (it1 != str1.crend() && it2 != str2.crend()) {
  int sum = (*it1 - '0') + (*it2 - '0') + carry;
  result.push_back('0' + (sum % 10));
  carry = sum / 10;
  it1++; it2++;
}

// We assume str1 is the longest, so copy digits from str1
while (it1 != str1.crend()) {
  int sum = (*it1 - '0') + carry;
  result.push_back('0' + (sum % 10));
  carry = sum / 10;
  it1++;
}

// This is an edge case: if str1.length == str2.length, carry might be 1
if (carry) {
  result.push_back('1');
}

// Reverse result
result = std::string(result.crbegin(), result.crend());
```

Comment: i used your idea (not copying), but getting some wrong answers. could you have a look?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Edit your question with some inputs and wrong outputs